# How to import selective rows from an Excel table?

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2010

I would like to ask, how to import selective rows from an excel database into a table. Another question: what is the maximum limit of row/column numbers in one table in Ms-Access 2010?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you can't import selective records.. either you sort your records before importing or you delete unwanted after importing. Second question > google for ms access limitations

Answer (score 0):

The best way you can achieve what you want is to use SSIS parkage to move the data from excel to access DB. if however, you do not have SSIS you can import all rows and delete the one you do not need.

Answer (score 0):

You can use SQL for import data from file as from table:

```
INSERT INTO Table1 (MyColumn1, MyColumn2, MyColumn3, MyColumn4) 
SELECT *
FROM [Sheet1$D3:E24] 
IN "C:\Temp\Test.xls" [Excel 8.0;HDR=YES;IMEX=0]
WHERE MyColumn1 > 0;
```

If `HDR=YES`, You can use names from header row as column names. If `IMEX=0`, Access determines column data type, if `IMEX=1`, considers all data as text, which may be very useful for complex data.

Comment: As of second question, see [link](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Access-2010-specifications-1e521481-7f9a-46f7-8ed9-ea9dff1fa854)